# Не работает unit файл для автозапуска

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-web-services

Имею вот такой unit файл, который загружен в /etc/systemd/system

```
[Unit]
Description=My Bot
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
bot.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/BSUTHelper
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/BSUTHelper/bot.py
RestartSec=10
Restart=always
 
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

После этого выполняю данные команды

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable bot.service
systemctl start bot.service
```

И при проверке статуса:
systemctl status bot.service
Я получаю данную ошибку:

```
● bot.service - My Bot
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/bot.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-01-28 11:32:34 UTC; 4s ago
    Process: 41868 ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/BSUTHelper/bot.py (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 41868 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jan 28 11:32:34 ip-172-31-47-200 systemd[1]: bot.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jan 28 11:32:34 ip-172-31-47-200 systemd[1]: bot.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Comment: проверь пути к файлу

Comment: Читайте journalctl для подробностей

Comment: @andreymal нашел проблему, не хватает модуля. Но при обычном запуске все нормально. т.к. я его устанавливал. как это исправить ?

Comment: А куда установили?

Comment: @andreymal pip3 install modul

Comment: В каком пользователе и в каком виртуальном окружении?

Comment: @andreymal у сервиса пользователь ubuntu

Comment: @andreymal я решил проблемму установив модуль для root.Но почемуэтот модуль нужен для рут если в инит фаиле у меня не указан рут пользователь

Comment: Если в файле не указан пользователь, то пользователь по умолчанию — рут. Укажите нужного пользователя, прописав опции User и Group